# Which regression model for percentage data with many zeros and ones?

Tags: regression, distributions, model-selection, skewness, histogram

I am analysing the share of a tree species at different forest locations. The data I am using is in percentage of the total species composition and I am modelling it based on the climatic probability of occurrence (continuous variable) and multiple site characteristics (categorical variables).

I was wondering which regression model would be most appropriate, as my target variable shows a lot of zeros and ones (meaning the species is not occurring at all or it is the only tree species at a certain location).

Here is a histogram with the distribution of my data.[image]

Comment: You say percent but your graph seems to imply that you are working an outcome or response which is a proportion or fraction. Buzzwords here are beta regression and logit regression with mild controversy about which is to be preferred.

Comment: I would strongly consider semiparametric ordinal regression, e.g., the proportional odds model as implemented in the R `rms` package `orm` function.

Comment: Not sure if that fits for you, but you may want to look at tobit and hurdle models.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to build 2 models:

- a classification model to 3 classes:0, 1, 2: the rest.
- regression model,only on the data with target differ then 0 and 1.

Then apply the regression model,only on those classified 2.